# Why are desiccated Ferengi green?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9, ferengi

In *DS9* ["The Nagus"](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Nagus_%28episode%29), we learn that Ferengi are vacuum-dessicated after death, a process which reduces them to powder form.  The powder is then packed into roughly 50 disks, which are then sold on the [Ferengi Futures Exchange](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Ferengi_Futures_Exchange).

The status of a Ferengi determines the price per disk.  For instance, the Grand Nagus himself, thought to be deceased in that episode, was going for 20 bars of gold-pressed latinum per disk, with a prediction that they would be worth even more down the line.

[image]

**Why are the remains green?**

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The official StarTrek.com page on [the Ferengi](http://www.startrek.com/database_article/ferengi) explicitly states that Ferengi blood is yellow and that the oxidisation/dessication of that blood causes it to turn green:

> **Ferengi blood is yellow, turning dark blue-green when oxidized.** Bodies are not
>   autopsied or even touched until after death rituals — which have been
>   seen to be the desiccation and sale of the remains.

The yellow blood can be seen in TNG: The Price.

[image]

Comment: Someone should update the Memory Alpha entry on ["Blood"](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Blood), which claims (with no citation) that the Ferengi have red blood.

Comment: Much better.  I have cleaned up the comments above.  Also, given the definitive nature of the answer, I see no reason not to go ahead and accept.

Comment: @Praxis - If I were to spend my time correcting Memory Alpha, I'd have no time to eat, sleep or bathe

Comment: @Richard Even worse, if you spent all your time updating Memory Alpha then you wouldn't be able to answer questions here with your usual haste.

Comment: @Richard : I wasn't certain that you did those things.

Comment: @Praxis - aperiodically.